# Would crab-cavalry work?

Tags: fauna, mounts, cavalry

Basically, giant crabs ridden by humans as cavalry, I just don't know if it's a good idea, and I could use some answers on how to make it work.

The setting is medieval fantasy.

The Giant Crabs won't really have a diverse diet, so ration problems, but then again they are giant crabs, with shells and claws, so I think this might be a good idea.

Crabalry is a good name.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How large are they relative to the people riding them? Is any kind of mechanism allowed that would enable the rider to put their sword or speak further to the side of them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endurance_riding _"European cavalry ... required the ability to carry 300 lb (140 kg) over 100 miles (160 km) in one day"_ ... so one question would be whether Giant Crabs could perform similar feat

Comment: Just noticed your username matches the question. Well played!

Comment: Sometimes, you get an idea, and you shouldn't ask "does this work?", but instead you ask "how do I make this work?". Crab cavalry is a baller idea and you need to do it.

Comment: Sure. The keyword is "fantasy". Brandon Sanderson uses crab-like creatures in the Stormlight series. His are slow moving creatures, but that doesn't mean yours have to be slow.

Comment: @Fred When you're as big as a small hill, speed isn't your greatest trait, but I don't recall them being especially slow.  They were generally fighting soldiers with magic swords and power armor after all.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson I don't recall them ever being used by fighting soldiers (other than pulling equipment). But according to Sanderson, "Chulls had only two speeds: slow shuffle and moderate shuffle." and "Chulls move at chull speed; they cannot be coaxed to go faster."

Comment: Thinking how crabs typically move, I can see this go sideways!

Comment: @Fred _Some_ of Brandon Sanderson's crustaceans move slowly. Others are maybe not so slow (E.g., Whitespines, Chasam Fiends, Axehounds)

Comment: If you've played "Return of the Obra Dinn", then yes, the crab riders are effective and terrifying.

Comment: But crabs of any size have not evolved as a load carrying species . . . Their skeleton being on the outside and their joints unsuitable for vertical loads makes them very unsuited for a plausible world. A comic world now is another matter . . .

Comment: With a name like crabalry you really don't have a choice. Crabs eat everything, so they can eat the fallen.  Seems terrifying.

Comment: @SolomonSlow You are correct. I was just thinking that chulls were the closest to crabs than the other crustaceans. But if you could tame a whitespine, it would be fast and terrifying to the enemy in a battle.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, are we handwaving crabs growing to ridable size and asking about the calvary aspect or are trying to justify the biology of ridable crabs?

Comment: At the size found on Earth, crabs have both strong limbs and resistant shells.

Write it well, and your readers will go along. Either way, if you try to scale up that strength or resistance, let alone both, you will hit the same limits evolution met millions of years ago… which is why crabs are so small today.

Squishy flesh or strong steel are bound by basic laws; strength depends on the square measure of the muscle or armour; the weight that muscle must move depends on the cube.

No 'giant' could be compared to a 'lesser' version.

Realistically, never. In good writing, try it!

Comment: Crabs like Woodlouse have GILLS so need to remain moist to BREATHE.  A cruel trainer could instil obedience by withholding water.

Answer (score 33):

## Not realistically, but they would have other uses

Before I proceed any further, remember the [Rule of Cool:](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool)

> The limit of the Willing Suspension of Disbelief for a given element is directly proportional to its awesomeness. Stated another way, all but the most pedantic of viewers will forgive liberties with reality as long as the result is wicked sweet or awesome.

So if you want a crabalry, have a crabalry. But if you want realism:

- The square cube law ensures that no crab like those from our world would ever be big enough for a human to ride. Your crabs would have to be some other kind of creature that evolved differently, and carcinized (yes, this is a word and a thing) at some point.
- Crabs need water. Even those who live on land need to be moist all the time. Horses can deal with dry conditions much better. This does not make a crabalry impossible, but makes it very limited to some areas.
- Being cold-blooded, your crabs won't be of much use in snowy conditions. Sure, crabs can move around in arctic waters, but have you seen how slow they are?
- Crabs need to molt every now and then. They will be useless while molting.
- Crabs have a very... primitive nervous system. You might think that a big crab will have a big brain, but the truth is that [there are crabs larger than dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_spider_crab) (almost 4 meters/yards from foot to foot when stretched), yet they still have small brains. That's because a bigger brain wouldn't be helpful where they evolved. Your crabs might be smart though, since their evolution is up to you.

But again: Rule of Cool. If you think it's cool, then lots of other people might think so too. Go for it. It would be cool to ride a beast that can run sideways and tear limbs from your foes with its pincers.

Crab cavalry aside, giant crabs would be great mounts for uneven terrain due do the amount, shape and layout of their legs. They would also be like elephants in that besides serving as mounts, they can pick up heavy stuff from the ground on their own and place it somewhere else. So rather than direct combat use, they might be great for construction and as beasts of burden. This still has a place in the military, as well as being useful in a civillian way.

Comment: I want to give you a bounty just for coining the term **crabalry** :-)

Comment: @Stephen I think you misattribute the coining of the term to The Square-Cube Law. The person asking the question describes crabalry and even has it's username crabalry.

Comment: ngl an amphibious crabalry assault on a major city would be sick... Just emerging from the water

Comment: Luckily I think the whole cold-blooded thing could be handwaved with a "snow crab" joke :p

Comment: As for using crabs as a beast of burden, it has actually been done in Brandon Sanderson's Stormlight series. Chulls.

Comment: “So rather than military use, they might be great for construction and as beasts of burden.” That might _be_ their military use. Construction and beasts of burden are massively important to a lot of military scenarios.

Comment: @KRyan you're right. I'll rephrase that to "rather than combat use".

Comment: I think the comparison with Elephants is great. Elephants were used in war (I think they counted as cavalry? At least they do in Age of Empires). I think crabs could serve a similar purpose.

Comment: Cold-blooded is less of a concern with large beasts: Square cube law makes giant crabs lose less heat, and movement will generate heat. This might mean you have to warm up your crabs before battle; if an unwise commander lets his crabs cool down too much, he might even be forced to kickstart them with bonfires.

Comment: @toolforger that... is... AWESOME!

Comment: @toolforger puts crabs in giant pots of water to warm them up... but then they start to smell good so they just keep adding more wood to the fire.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Well, you still need fire to heat the water, so the enemy will still see that you're warming up your crabs.

Answer (score 19):

I’ll treat the Crabs like any medieval fantasy creature. There’s no point in watching something like LotR and then saying “wraiths don’t exist” or “those Trolls would collapse under their own weight”.

These are big horse-sized or bigger crabs, people can ride them, they are domesticated enough to function as war animals.

If you ask if Crabs could be Cavalry you run into the same problem as when people ask questions about mechs versus tanks. Of course it can’t compete or do the same things because they are different. So instead of asking if Crabs can be Cavalry, ask what function a Crab could have within an army! There are likely ways Crabalry can be its own thing!

Crabs won’t have the speed of horse Cavalry, and that’s OK. Because unlike horses your Crabs would be far better protected against spear and pike formations. Whenever the horse Cavalry has to stop or risk running into a prepared formation, your Crabalry can move up. You wave a spear at them? They can bat them away, attempt to grab them relatively safely and have natural armor against it. Which any military mind would add some more armor on, reinforced leather most likely as club-like weapons would be the best against crabs.

Crabalry would fill its own niche. It would likely function as heavy infantry that is highly resistant to Cavalry charges. It would also accelerate the evolution of Pike formations as the hammer/axe part would be one of the best tools against Crab shells that large.

Comment: The lucerne is developed early with an extra attachment to hold a large wedge of lemon.

Comment: Presumably crabs are also excellent for climbing up a castle wall?

Comment: @Joe I assume that would depend on the type of crab. Although even if you had something like a Coconut crab I’m not sure if they can climb walls very well. I only see them climb coconut trees and the occasional trashcan. That said, if you had some strong ladders close together I would totally see them climb up there.

Answer (score 13):

## TOO SMALL

Giant land crabs already exist. (Un)fortunately they are still too small. The largest crab is the coconut crab:

[image]

This is not only the largest crab. In fact this is the largest terrestrial arthropod. These things weigh about 5kg and are about a metre long. For comparison:

[image]

It seems the [largest known extinct land arthropod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropleura) is a 2 metre long millipede that is estimated to weigh about 50kg. That's the weight of a St Bernard dog. Still too small to ride. At least if you're a human:

[image]

The crab is too small for Ripley to ride without smooshing it with her rock-hard butt. The crab is even too small for the little girl she rescues in that film.

Since [everything eventually turns into a crab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carcinisation) the assumption is that if a bigger crab was possible we would have seen one by now. So a crab big enough to ride is hard to believe.

To solve this problem I suggest your giant crabs be normal crabs who had Enlarge Crab cast on them. This is the household name for modification II.a4 of Enlarge Monster designed specially to work on crabs. This spell is known to ignore such trivial considerations as whether the target would be too heavy to move after being scaled up. A wizard did it.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the references to Aliens, the "Enlarge Crab" houserule, and the general humorous tone of the reply. ^^

Answer (score 13):

### Cry Havok! and let slip the crabs of war!!!

[image]

The question should not so much be "COULD" you ride a crab as "is this the best use of giant crabs on the battlefield?"

There is one historical unit that giant crabs would replace much better than cavalry: war dogs.  The point of a warhorse is to deliver a deadly warrior as fast as you can to (and from) the enemy lines. But giant crabs will be much slower than horses, and would be so well equipped with natural weapons and armor, that putting a knight on top of one would be a waste of a knight. War dogs were different. They were used to attack the enemy formation on their own using thier natural weapons. This created panic and disorder in the enemy ranks in preparation for an infantry or cavalry charge.

War crabs would fill this role even better because crabs have a resemblance to spiders causing humans to have a natural fear of them.  They also have thick armor and powerful claws that put dog fur and teeth to shame. So put those crabs on the front line and save your horsemen for what cavalry does best: Skirmishing, out-flanking, and chasing routs.

Comment: "crabs have a resemblance to spiders causing humans to have a natural fear of them." Do we know for sure that fear of spiders isn't actually an evolved fear of the long-extinct war crab?

Comment: @PastychomperthanksMonica More likely war scorption.

Comment: crab calvary makes eating your mount a lot more enjoyable if nothing else. "Bob stop asking if we need to eat our crabs, the supply carts are still half full!"

Answer (score 8):

It would be a terrifying and effective mount if it was trainable. Which normal crabs aren't.

The biggest drawback is how much room it would take. you couldn't have close formations, the legs would tangle and it just takes so much more room than a horse. And formations can be critical in medieval battles.

I'd use them like tanks, stick a box on their backs with some archers or artillery and you have mobile, terrifying and self-defending troops which may well be invulnerable to heavy calvalry charges.

Comment: "you couldn't have close formations, the legs would tangle and it just takes so much more room than a horse." So what you're saying is that lobster cavalry is the way to go?

Comment: FYI, [this blog post](https://www.clickertraining.com/node/2314) suggests that crabs are in fact trainable. (Which makes sense, since most animals are to some extent.)

Answer (score 7):

Yes and No.

So - On the Yes side - a Giant Crab (able to be ridden by a Human and let's put aside the exoskeleton weight limit thing for a moment) is going to be big (duh!), is going to be armored and has 2 offensive weapons.

This would mean that in the role of say Heavy Cavalry, they would fair pretty well - able to smash apart an enemy line, the terror factor of a giant pincer and being able to hoist a man up and cut them in half is not to be underestimated in terms of psychological impact.

However...

On the No side - What made Cavalry such an effective tool is **speed** a Galloping horse is faster than a Human. Even a nice steady canter is much faster than a mans Jog - and this is where Cavalry came into it's own - the ability to outflank and outmaneuver infantry. This also includes your scout cavalry - being able to go a great distance at speed and report what you saw and come back.

Then you've also got the harassments of your enemies supply lines - There's some great examples of this in the Sharpe TV series that shows how that works - suddenly a light cavalry division comes around the corner, engages a slow moving supply train *slash, Slash SLASH!* then disengages before they can rally to a defense and return fire.

In this area, even a Giant Crab, assuming the same speed of the fastest crab is only capable of 3-4 m/s, compares to a horses' 14 m/s.

So this form of Cavalry a Crab wouldn't be effective.

Comment: Why would a giant crab be as slow as a normal size one? A crab sized horse wouldn't be as fast as a full size one. Humans can do much better than 4m/s

Comment: @Kilisi - I think the major limiting factor is the the mechanics of locomotion - Even if we account for a Giant Crab being able to move a bit faster, owing to stride length, I don't think we are going to be getting much more speed. And sure Humans can do better than 4m/s - in terms of a soldier, armed and armored - I think 4 m/s is being *extremely* generous. Most Spec-Ops guys today when doing a forced march are doing about 6 Kph which is 1.6 m/s - *really* fit guys can do closer to 8 Kph so 2.2 m/s

Comment: You may be treating Cavalry too literally. Giant Crabs could likely play the same role as Hannibal's Elephants for example. That is, (Very) Heavy Cavalry meant to charge into the thick of it and demoralize, or to hold the Center (as the enemy is reluctant to engage). Different types of Cavalry have different roles, and Crabs not being Light Cavalry doesn't mean they can't be Cavalry at all.

Comment: The charge not at all the purpose of war elephants, and indeed when used this way they were isolated and slaughtered easily by light screening troops targeting their riders. Elephants had to be closely supported by infantry formations, making them distinct from heavy cavalry which *did* operate independently (but also did not charge into the face of dense infantry formations).

Answer (score 7):

[Crabs walk sideways](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdRMHN2phkA). This will make it extremely inconvenient to attack enemy units directly in front of your formation. Either the crabs will need to turn to one side in order to approach the line of contact, causing each crab and rider to turn their backs to half the enemy, or the crabs will need to *sidle* across the battle line, greatly reducing their effectiveness as shock troops.

On the other hand, no formation could be more exquisitely suited to a *flanking* attack then a company of lancers mounted on battle crabs.

Lobsters, now...

Comment: Crabs can walk in any direction, and even if your typical eating crab walks fastest sideways, it is not the only type of crab.

Comment: Even if the crabs would only walk sideways, the riders could just turn 90⁰ on the saddle. +1 for the point about flanking.

Comment: You'd probably be best off using crabs to attack *both* flanks simultaneously. There's a name for that, but I don't recall what it is at the moment.

Comment: @GuyG What better use for the crabs then a pincer movement?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the naysayers are on about.  This is awesome.

Crabalry is a great idea.  Terrifying. Pincers. They eat you while you're alive. Armored. Fast. Fearless. Hungry.

Realism? If I wanted realism I'd work some unpaid overtime.

How to "make" it work?  Don't bother, just say it does. Or better yet, just show it working: "Sir Bob steered mighty Gorgonoplex to the left into the King's retainers. While Bob struck down a bodyguard, Gorgonoplex grabbed the Duke of Edinburgh in his mighty crushing claw. Tough break, that ain't gonna buff out!"

Light Warcrabs (say, one metric ton, or about 2200 lbs) are saddled for an armored man wielding a flail.

Medium Warcrabs can easily carry two men. One of them could be an archer.

Heavy Warcrabs could weigh in at 5 metric tons and sport a tower of wood on their backs large enough to provide cover for 4 men.

Comment: So that's what happened to Prince Philip...

Answer (score 2):

### Crabs Would Be Maneuverable

I can’t really say much about the speed of the crabs, it would probably depend on lots of different factors, but they would definitely have one major advantage: the ability to sidestep and basically move in any direction.  This added maneuverability could prove very helpful for evading projectiles, especially if this breed of war crab has fast reflexes.  Also, the hide could be much tougher than that of a horse, possibly making them better equipped against anti-cavalry weapons such as lances.

So in summary, yes, I think crab cavalry or “crabalry” would work.